# Find the ratio among columns

Tags: awk

I have some input files of the following format:

```
File1.txt     File2.txt      File3.txt
1  2          1 6            1  20
2  3          2 9            2  21
3  7          3 14           3  28
```

Now I need to output a new single file using AWK with three columns, the first column remains the same, and it is the same among the three files (just an ordinal number).

However for 2nd and the 3rd column of this newly created file, I need to values of the 2nd column of the second file divided by the values of the 2nd column of the 1st file, also the values of the second column of the third file divided by the value of the 2nd column of the first file. In other words, the 2nd columns for the 2nd and 3rd file divided by the 2nd column of the first file.
e.g.:

```
Result.txt
1  3  10
2  3  7
3  2  4
```

Comment: ok got a solution:
paste file1, file2, file3 | awk '{print $1, ($4/$2), ($6/$2)}'

Comment: Have you considered using the Linux command "join" first to create one file, and then awk?

Comment: @Dan Cron, no, not really. I just needed a quick hack, I knew it that it should be easy using awk.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multidimensional matrix to store the values:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next}
    {b[$1,ARGIND]=$2/a[$1]}
    END {for (i in a) 
           print i,b[i,2],b[i,3]
        }' f1 f2 f3
```

#### Test

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$2; next} {b[$1,ARGIND]=$2/a[$1]} END {for (i in a) print i,b[i,2],b[i,3]}' f1 f2 f3
1 3 10
2 3 7
3 2 4
```

Comment: ok, I got a simpler solution:
paste file1, file2, file3 | awk '{print $1, ($4/$2), ($6/$2)}'
but thanks!

Comment: @3.14 nice one also! I like that one also. Mine is just `awk`, yours uses `paste` cleverly.